# PyCharm cannot find the packages in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pycharm

I have the latest PyCharm CE and am using it with `virtualenv`. I have defined the interpreter as the interpreter in the `virtualenv`. The Project Interpreter window in PyCharm lists all the packages I have installed. I  confirmed this by running `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and running through the packages manually.

My problem is that PyCharm won't find certain includes in its editor windows, like `Flask-Login`:

In `from flask.ext.login import current_user, login_user, logout_user, login_required` the includes `current_user, login_user, logout_user, login_required` are all marked as unresolved references.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I've had this issue once and it was just jetbrains being lame.  Try `File -> Invalidate Caches` and restart PyCharm.  You might have to wait some minutes for it to rebuild the caches

Comment: In my case, I messed up my venv by accidentally adding a new venv where my old one previously was instead of just selecting the old one. The solution was to delete the venv directory out of my Pycharm project (this deleted my local venv as well). After that, I set up a fresh venv and added that one to Pycharm correctly this time.

Comment: It's 2021 now and I have still the same problem... (Pycharm 2021.3.1 Professional E.). None of the current answers worked for me.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The problem may lay in PyCharm picking up faulty 'Interpreter Paths' for your virtual environment. Go here:

```
PyCharm (menu) -> Preferences (Menu option)
               -> Project: <name> (Dropdown) 
               -> Project Interpreter (Menu option)
               -> 'Settings' button (Looks like a gear)
               -> More (Menu option)
               -> Select your virtualenv interpreter
               -> Click 'Show paths for interpreter' button (on bottom of list window)
```

Now that you're in this (admittedly tortuously found) location, you should see paths being used by this interpreter. If my theory is correct, these are pointing to global system locations. To add the virtual environment paths, you should click the `+` button and add corresponding paths that exist inside your virtual environment. Once you're done with this, it's a good idea to select the global system paths and click `-` to remove them. Click apply, and go to `File -> Invalidate caches / Restart` to reload PyCharm.

This should get your interpreter to be pointed to the correct location for the libraries you've installed into your virtualenv, and you should no longer be getting the import error. Note that even with this fix you will not see your libraries under the `Project Interpreter`, but they should be being loaded.

Comment: This is the correct procedure in fact (although it is somehow ridiculous that PyCharm is so primitive on these things).

Comment: **File -> Invalidate caches / Restart to reload PyCharm.**  what I hadn't done.

Answer (score 9):

In the newest version of PyCharm (2016.1.4 in my case):

- Settings
- Project: name of project

  - project Interpreter
  - at the right side there will be a dropdown where you can choose the interpreter. There should be venv options.

See image below for better explanation (like they said, 1 picture worth thousands word)

[image: Setting python interpreter]

Comment: This answer is unclear; what do I do with the venv options? Are you trying to reference some other comment tacitly?

Comment: @rrlamichhane the question is explicitly stating that they use it with virtualenv, and `venv` is the default folder created when using virtualenv. I believe you just need to use the Python interpreter in the virtualenv. If your installed packages are in the virtualenv, it should just work.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue (includes are still not being found) even after Nathaniel Ford and dieend's **correct** suggestion. Make sure that your run/debug configuration as correct python interpreter selected:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Also note the accepted answer is no longer applicable to PyCharm menu structure. It is now `File > Settings > Project > Project Interpreter > Gear Icon > Show All`

The following steps detail the "nuclear" option:

1. Delete your project virtual environment directory (e.g. `/venv`)
2. Delete all other interpreters listed in menu option accessible by the route listed at the top of this post.
3. Close PyCharm
4. Delete the `.idea` directory in your project folder
5. Restart PyCharm, opening the project folder.
6. Go through the process of configuring a new interpreter.

That will pretty much get you starting from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that every time I open a different project it still has the venv from the project I was previously working on.

What I do is:

ctrl-alt-s (to go into preferences), then Project Interpreter/settings (gear icon), show all, then remove all the venv environments that aren't your current project (use the - sign).  Restart, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Open up `Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpreter`, do you see the module there?

If yes, you might have another file somewhere in your project have the same name as `flask.ext.login`, this prevents pycharm from locating the actual module.

If no, you can click on the `...` beside your interpreter and select `more...`, select your interpreter and at the bottom (beside the filter), click the `Show paths for the selected interpreter`, you can add the path of your module there.

Comment: Tried what you suggested but it didn't work for me. I even created a new virtualenv with pypy but the same includes are still not being found.

Comment: sorry, I have no idea how to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the easiest solution was to open the project in the root directory (my project has a server and client directories, thus the root directory contained both of them). When you open the project in the root directory, it is able to find the dependencies without messing with pycharm settings as it uses them by convention.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents on this topic as I struggled myself with it recently.
Nathaniel Ford's answer is the good one except that this part:

```
               -> Select your virtualenv interpreter
```

was unclear to me.

I tried several times with

```
~/.virtualenvs/python-audition-2.9/bin/python
```

whereas it only worked with

```
~/.virtualenvs/python-audition-2.9/local/bin/python
```

Notice the **`.../local/...`** in the latter path? It was really important in my case. And don't forget to `File -> Invalidate caches / Restart` to reload PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the lib directory in my virtual environment to sources in the PyCharm CE settings helped me.
My steps:

1. Preferences -> Project:  -> Project Structure

[Scrin1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfrU4.png)

2. Select the directory where you installed the libraries. In my case, this is "lib".
3. Mark the directory as "source".

[Scrin2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8ZiE.jpg)

After these actions, all my libraries were correctly imported into the py files I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution: (PyCharm 2022.2.3) and Python 3.11.0 on Win11:

- Create new venv Environment for the project, DO NOT inherit site-packages
- Check, if jupyter-server uses new venv (Settings->Language&Frameworks->Jupyter->Jupyter Server)

Install all required packages (inbcluding jupyter!) to venv (e.g., requirements.txt and PyCharm)
Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on WINDOWS and LINUX and i continue to have same issue each time i move project to different location... What works for me is to

**rename venv directory**

inside your project to venvxx(or w/e you want)
and then

**create NEW virtual env**

through pycharm settings
After that you

**paste lib directory**

from venvxx(or w/e named it)

**to lib inside fresh new venv**

and it should work now at least for me it does i hope this helps someone out there! After that restart pycharm and your terminal should be working fine

Answer (score 0):

**Here's corner case:** if you moved your project folder to some other place in your file-system, then some caching of PyCharm on your project folder, might be forcing and old interpreter path behind the scenes, even though you defined a new one. And of course, you'll see no packages from your Virtualenv, for the interpreter object itself, was not recognized by PyCharm.

If that's the case, there are two options:

1. erase the folder `.idea` from your project's root folder, close PyCharm and open it up again, in order to set up your Python interpreter.
2. invalidate PyCharm cache: `File -> Invalidate Caches...`

For debugging PyCharm logs: `Help -> Show Log in Files...`

On Ubuntu, generally, the main PyCharm log is available on the following path:

- `~/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2023.1/log/idea.log`: the directory `PyCharmCE2023.1` is named based on your PyCharm installation date, so it might be a different directory on your file-system.

You can use PyCharm while visualizing the log file and the possible errors related with the interpreter setup, in order to figure out the issue:

```
$ tail -f .cache/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2023.1/log/idea.log 
2023-06-01 20:37:35,376 [22188086]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-06-01 20:41:17,038 [22409748]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-06-01 20:42:02,206 [22454916]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-06-01 20:42:23,752 [22476462]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-06-01 20:42:32,623 [22485333]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-06-01 20:49:01,659 [22874369]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-06-01 20:49:09,130 [22881840]   INFO - #c.i.w.i.i.j.s.JpsGlobalModelSynchronizerImpl - Saving global entities to files
2023-06-01 20:49:11,019 [22883729]   INFO - #c.i.i.a.RevealFileAction - Timed out
2023-06-01 20:49:11,019 [22883729]   INFO - #c.i.i.a.RevealFileAction - Nautilus-Share-Message: 20:49:01.414: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score -1):

Goto /venv/bin/ and check all activate scripts. You venv path might be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I was not able to assign existing virtual environment to my project, but after going to

> File -> Settings -> project interpreter-> show all-> click on '+'

to create a new virtual environment or we can choose the existing virtual environment, I am able to assign and use the existing virtual enviroments.