# PyCharm cannot find installed packages: keras

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, keras

I installed pycharm-2016.1.4 in my PC running Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed Keras (a Python package) using `pip install keras` and PyCharm **can** find it **before**. But it **cannot** find Keras **now**. I do not modify any settings, so this problem may be wired. My Python version is Python 2.7.

[image]

I use `pip list` to verify that I have Keras installed:

[image]

But check this package in PyCharm by using: Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter. Keras is **NOT** in the package list. (The interpreter used is the same as the result of `which python` in terminal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know what happened, but the problem solved with the following steps.

1. Uninstall old keras
2. Re-install keras: `pip install keras`

Then I can `import keras` in pycharm.

**NOTE:** It is strange since I have keras installed but cannot find it in **Project Interpreter's package list**.

Comment: Very very strange, but i'm happy that you have found a solution! :)

Answer (score 9):

This is strange, but you can install Keras directly through Pycharm.

You can follow this steps:

- Go to **Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter**
- Click on **plus icon** in the top-right corner
- Search **Keras** and press on **Install Package**

Please let me know if this procedure solve your issue.

Comment: I have tried method as you say before, but **NO** packages in the list. I tried your answer just now and no packages as well. Steps: Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter, click the green "add" button, search keras but no packages in the list.

Comment: Do you use a virtualenv? Are you sure that you selected the correct Interpreter?

Comment: I do not use virtualenv. I only have one interpreter: anaconda's python-2.7.

Comment: Moreover, I find I cannot install ant package using your method. Maybe the **install package** in my pycharm crash?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, and I use a virtualenv, @Giordano, can you please help me with installation of Keras using PyCharm? Everytime I try to install it using the above method, PyCharm shows me an error "40:490 execution erro:The directory '/Users/varij/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled."

Comment: Hi @varijkap, seems that you have some permission problems with the folder /Users/varij/Library/Caches/pip/http or its parent.

Comment: But normal pip operations are successful, I am able to install keras without sudo through the terminal, Anyways, I solved the issue by changing the Project interpreter directory by following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35141307/2228983) answer

Answer (score 2):

Use

```python
import tensorflow.python.keras
```

instead.

Comment: This is a 6 year old question, do you mind putting an explanation as to why the above works? (I ask because others have flagged the answer)

Answer (score 1):

After installing tensorflow and keras, try the following:

```py
import keras as ks
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
```

Answer (score 0):

To clearify Giordano's answer:

1. You should have installed tensorflow or any other framework where keras can be used on top of.
2. Create a virtualenv and set this as your project interpreter. This is a working solution for me: [Installing tensorflow on Pycharm (Mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998018/installing-tensorflow-on-pycharm-mac)
3. Got to **preferences -> Project: -> Project Interpreter**
4. Click on the plus sign on the bottom left corner
5. Search Keras and install the package.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

if you ever have installed in python:

- Go to **File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter**
- **Click the gear-> Add..->System interpreter**
- Choose the python version that have installed keras

Answer (score 0):

I am running through a training video series and, with Conda installed on my Centos 7 system, I could not get Keras to load properly.  My solution was to use VirtualEnv for my Python Interpreter.  I followed the steps here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add_new_project_interpreter

Comment: Can you include the steps you followed in your answer? If the link you included ever stops working, your answer loses it's value.