# PyCharm cannot detect PyCrypto, M2Crypto, or PyOpenSSL even after installing it with pip3

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pycharm

I've installed 3 packages in the command line with `pip3 install <package name>` but PyCharm can't seem to locate those packages. I don't know if that matters but I'm using version 3.9 of the interpreter and after installing each package, I saw in the background task list that PyCharm was indexing.

I tried running the commands again and they all said `Requirement already satisfied`.

I also tried hovering my mouse over the underlined package name in PyCharm and clicking on **install package** but that seemed to do nothing.

I also tried to locate the packages in the command line with the `locate` command. Nothing was returned for pycrypto or m2crypto, but when I searched for pyopenssl, I saw numerous paths, none of which I think are what I'm looking for (the closest one I saw was `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py`. Maybe that's the module?) Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: Did you define the path of the interpreter ?

Comment: Do you mean if I configured it? If so, yes. The path is /usr/local/bin/python3.9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PIP Cryptography Failing to Install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59143740/pip-cryptography-failing-to-install)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I did those steps in the question but when I try to type something like `import pycrypto` or any other package name, it still gives me a red underline saying *unresolved reference pycrypto*