# Pandas / numpy are installed but cannot import. Have tried everything

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pip

I have uninstalled and re-installed numpy and pandas using pip (see photo) but in pycharm, they cannot be imported - "No module"

[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0icA.png)
[pycharm output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpcm6.png)

your help would be much appreciated

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59143740/pip-cryptography-failing-to-install/59212843#59212843) answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes get an error in PyCharm. Have you tried restarting PyCharm?

There are ways to solve the error:

1. Check the python environment where you installed numpy and pandas.
2. You can also create a virtual environment where you will install these libraries and activate this environment to pycharm.